# JavaScript: base64url according to RFC4648

Tags: javascript, base64, urlencode, url-encoding

I'm looking for a (fast) standard implementation for base64url according to [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) in JavaScript.

So far I came up with:

```
var base64url = window.btoa(url).replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/=/g, '');
```

Anything faster?

Comment: @dunkendid you find a solution for this? I cant find one myself other then node libs but i dont want to use webpack/browserrify on node libs and put it into browser.